# CSS grid view fit to screen with minimum 2 divs

Tags: html, css

I have some divs and have to make a grid.
now i need of:
1) in horizontally there are always minimum 2 divs, maximum infinity

2) horizontally divs are always fit to screen

3) you can set a min-width for divs , bcz divs can not be large from 200px

4) divs are flexible with any type of browser

5) only css

Comment: what code you have ? can you post your current code used or tried ?? secondly your point no. 2 and 3 are contradictory... max width can be 200px or less and till div always fit to screen ?? if there are only 2 divs, total width will be 400 px.. then how they can be fit to screen ??

Comment: if it is for a single row flex + width for the children will do. any code to share or is it a job offer ? ...

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack-overflow. When asking a question it's important to provide as much info as possible to help people give you the best answer possible. Please review this article [mcve] & add some more context to your question, along with some info on how you've tried to solve the problem yourself :)

Comment: Dear manish, i told about the max width, thats why when there are 2 divs it can be large highest 400px, or less,.. this less means it can suppose 230px total (115, 115) ...

Answer (score 0):

```
#parent {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            padding:2px;
        }
        .child {
            background: url(https://www.sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-200kb.jpg);
            flex: 1;
            min-width: 25%;               
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid #382800;
            position: relative;  
            padding-top:35%;
        }
        @media (max-width: 700px) {
            .child {
                min-width: 33.33%;
                padding-top: 46.66%;
            }
        }

        @media (max-width: 400px) {
            .child {
                min-width: 50%;
                padding-top: 70%;
            }
        }
        .child_name {
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            color: white;
            padding: 12px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom:0px;
            right:0px;
            left:0px;
        }
```